# Testing ScheduledExecutionerService in Java

Tags: java, schedule

I'm scheduling an event twice a year using ScheduledExecutionerService but I'm really unsure of how I go about testing this. Where do I start with testing a scheduler and how can I be sure it kicked off at the correct time and date?

Comment: You have a long-running application, and the computer running it does not reboot for half a year? `ScheduledExecutionerService` is a Class intended to manage threads, and maybe timed execution within the application, but it's not persistent, nor can you shedule something across multiple executions of the same application (out of the box). If that is your intention, then you need to extend here. Otherwise, this class is not the correct medium for your use case.

Comment: I have to do some configuration changes around daylight saving when clocks go forward/backward. I want to be sure the scheduler kicked off and that the hour went forward/backward, so then I can make changes. Basically, I'll schedule for the first DST change, then re-schedule for the second one after I am finished with the first scheduled event.

Comment: Is you application a server? Can you really expect your application to run without interruption or reboot? If you schedule something with `ScheduledExecutorService` and restart the application, the scheduled job is not executed (because it was scheduled in another JVM-Lifecycle). You need to persist the job in some form, or at least reschedule the job on restart. To test this, write a testcast (unit test) that schedules shorter and does something else (e.g. log some message). The testing of the clock-setting can probably be done independently.

Comment: No It's not a server and it would be possible that the application could be rebooted? What would be recommeded to schedule an event then? When I was looking this up, ScheduledExecutionerService was the main one recommended?

Comment: It was recommended, because it can (more precisely than most other options) schedule something for future execution, but you still have to instantiate the execution service each application start, and you can then probably decide based on the current date, what the next DST-toggles are, and schedule them. As your job does (probably) not require objects that only exist in one application-lifecycle, you can probably do this without worry.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but you have to take care to reschedule the DST-toggle jobs each application launch, because jobs scheduled with `ScheduledExecutorService` are not persisted in any form, and are therefore only scheduled until the application is terminated.

I would do it like this:

- write a utility that sets the correct DST-mode that can be called without parameters, and that figures out how to set the DST on it's own, based on the current global time.
- On startup, run the method once.
- On startup, schedule two (reoccuring) toggles, on the respective dates (and time), running that method.

This way, your application will automatically correct DST-mode on the respective dates, if it runs during a DST-toggle.

Comment: I've been playing around with the scheduler and it works great. I defintely need to schedule this in the application startup as you say, but that's good, as I can still use ScheduleExecutionerService. Is there a way I can test this works then? How can I be sure it did in fact kick off at the DST change dates.

Comment: Log a message comparing the time before and after, for example? Log something like 'time was set from X to Y.' Or if you have in fact no server, and thus probably no logging, you could pop up a message, or add something to some other form of client message, depending on what you develop.

Comment: OK thanks, I can log messages for now as we have this setup.